# axios request cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I am trying to make a backend request to a server and I continue to get a `response.data` back that is some HTML as a string that says `TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined`

I need to pass it a `data` object that looks like so:

```
const data = {
  visitorId,
  patientId: oldPatientId,
  doctorId
}
```

and I need to pass it a json web token like so:

```
const userJWT = jwt.sign(
  {
    _id: visitorId,
    refreshCount: 0
  },
  this.localConfig.spyrt.jwtSecret
)
```

and headers that look like so:

```
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${userJWT}`
}
```

I am doing this inside an asynchronous method like so:

```
async jwtTest(visitorId: number, oldPatientId: number, doctorId: number): Promise<void> {
  const data = {
      visitorId,
      patientId: oldPatientId,
      doctorId
    }

    const userJWT = jwt.sign(
      {
        _id: visitorId,
        refreshCount: 0
      },
      this.localConfig.spyrt.jwtSecret
    )
    
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${userJWT}`
    }

    if (this.localConfig.spyrt.active) {
      const dto = await axios.post(visitURL, data, {headers}).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
}
```

I am concerned that my axios code is not set up correctly. I am getting cannot read property undefined and a 500 `statusCode` error.

I have consulted with the axios documentation to the best of my ability. Does anyone see anything wrong with my setup?

I tried this implementation:

```
if (this.localConfig.spyrt.active) {
  await axios.post(visitURL, data, {headers}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
})
}
```

and with this one I get the exact same response.

The closest I have to understanding that API is the previous engineer's code whose setup looked like this:

```
try {
  let response = await fetch(visitURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + acct.jwt
     },
     body: JSON.stringify(visit)
    });
    if (response.ok) {
     let result = await response.json();
     callback(result);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Model: createVisit failed!');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

Comment: What specifically is undefined, where? Give a [mre]. If it's `dto`, then note that not only does `.then(() => { console.log("something") })` mean you now have a promise of undefined, it's followed by `.then(() => {})` that would do that anyway.

Comment: From the description it sounds like an error is happening *server-side*, not *client-side*.

Comment: @David, so does that mean there is nothing wrong with my implementation?

Comment: @Daniel: Maybe?  Testing and debugging can confirm that.  But any such testing and debugging that you do should be very explicit about what exact error is being observed and where it's being observed.  Is this error message being returned from the server?

Comment: yes I am getting from console log, inside the data property I am getting an HTML string that says `Cannot read property of undefined` and I am also getting a request failed with status of 500

Comment: @jonrsharpe, so even when I remove that empty `.then()` I still get cannot read property of undefined.

Comment: @David, so I am not familiar with the server I am trying to hit, the person who is familiar suggested that the problem is in my axios setup because when making a Postman request to another endpoint in the same server, it works.

Comment: Again, the `.then` before it, which logs then returns nothing, _also_ causes the overall promise chain to resolve undefined. But if that message is in the _response body_ then how you're handling the response isn't all that relevant - 500 means server-side error, and you've shown us nothing about the API implementation. Are you making the wrong request? Maybe, but even if so it's hard to say what the right one would be.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, understood, thank you.

Comment: Also note that conventionally (albeit with no guarantees this holds for the implementation you're interacting with) 5xx implies that the problem was outside your control, the request was fine but the server ran into trouble trying to respond to it, whereas 4xx would tell you there was a problem with the request you were making. On the other hand, given you say Postman succeeds but Axios fails, that suggests the problem is in your implementation of the request.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I tried a different implementation and I gat back the exact same response. Also, the Postman test was not with the same endpoint, it was with an `auth/login` endpoint with a simple email and password, but this one is a `/api/v1/visit` endpoint and I do not have eyes on its API and how its implemented. Does it necessarily stand that if one endpoint works, then other endpoints should work is my question, which not knowing the API nobody can answer that for me. You may ask why not try this endpoint on Postman, but I cannot without the `if` conditional for regulatory reasons.

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you think we can do for you, then. If it was a case of "how do I express <response> in Axios" it would be answerable, albeit likely to be too specific to your use case to be useful for SO. You need to find out what request is expected, look at the request Axios is actually making, and resolve any differences. I don't see why you'd think changing from an arrow to a regular function or using JSON.stringify would change the _response_ you're getting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, so I was being told that the issue is definitely in how I wrote the axios request and so what I was looking for is another set of eyes to say "oh yeah you wrote that wrong", but it sounds like the issue is without knowing more about this API I am hitting or trying to hit with this request, there is not much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

You would either use async/await or promise, but not both in the same invocation. Quickest fix would be:

```
try {
  const dto = await axios.post(visitURL, data, {headers})
  const data = dto.data
  console.log(data)
} catch (err) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

Comment: They are entirely interoperable, but the OP appears to be using them incorrectly.

Comment: Not in the same invocation

Comment: Yes in the same invocation. E.g. `const data = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json())` would work just fine (although I'd agree it can be confusing to mix them like that). The problem is (maybe) that the OP is chaining `.then` callbacks that _don't return anything_.

Comment: ok, I admit I did not know or have seen that

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle, I get the same results with your implementation.

Comment: @Daniel You can `console.log(dto)`  If `dto` does not have the property `data` then you would need to look on the server side. Another way to confirm is to use `curl` or `postman` or `insomnia`. From there you can narrow down to the server side or code on client side

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle, when I try your implementation, the `data` property value is a long string of HTML saying Cannot read property of undefined` and the same 500 error.

Comment: If you try `postman` or `insomnia` or `curl` and see the same, then you should focus on the server side.

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle, the `const dto = await axios.post(visitURL, data, {headers})` never gets executed, it goes into the if conditional and then jumps to catch.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: make sure you're properly accessing your response object**

I ran into this post and my issue ended up being because I was missing a '.data' on my object access

I had this (wrong)

```
axios
      .post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_URL}/score/`, {'day':today})
      .then(response => {
        response.categories.forEach(element => console.log(element.score));
      })
```

vs the correct:

```
axios
      .post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_URL}/score/`, {'day':today})
      .then(response => {
        response.data.categories.forEach(element => console.log(element.score));
      })
```